# Why does an even $x$ imply $y^2=-2 \pmod 8$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, congruence-relations

I am very new to modular arithmetic, and I encountered the following statement on page 7 of [this paper](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf):
If $x$ is even then $y^2 \equiv-2\pmod{8}$

The equation in question is $y^2=x^3-2$

I do not understand why. Could someone give a hint or a nudge in the right direction as to why this is true? My knowledge of modular arithmetic is sparse and I have absolutely no idea where to look in this case.

Comment: If $x$ is even, then it can be written as $2z$. Then $x^3 = 8z^3$.

Comment: @AhmedHussein Thank you! I don't know how I missed that!

Comment: BTW, the title says $y\equiv-2\pmod8$, the body says $y^2\equiv-2\pmod8$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $x$ as a general even number, put $x=2n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then
$$y^{2}=(2n)^{3}-2=8n^{3}-2$$
Modulo $8$ this leaves a remainder of $-2$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following cases:

- $x\equiv\color\red0\pmod8 \implies x^3-2 \equiv\color\red0^3-2\equiv  0-2\equiv 0\cdot8-2\equiv-2\pmod8$
- $x\equiv\color\red2\pmod8 \implies x^3-2 \equiv\color\red2^3-2\equiv  8-2\equiv 1\cdot8-2\equiv-2\pmod8$
- $x\equiv\color\red4\pmod8 \implies x^3-2 \equiv\color\red4^3-2\equiv 64-2\equiv 8\cdot8-2\equiv-2\pmod8$
- $x\equiv\color\red6\pmod8 \implies x^3-2 \equiv\color\red6^3-2\equiv216-2\equiv27\cdot8-2\equiv-2\pmod8$